# Indexed file searches when using pydev on a remote project?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Searched ad nauseum for a clear answer and not finding one, so...

My normal setup at work is pydev running on Eclipse via X11. Life is good, I can search for strings in my 4000 python source files in ~5 seconds. I figure there's got to be some sort of indexing/caching going on.

Now, trying to work remotely with Eclipse 3.7.2 on my OSX box I've got RSE installed, and have done the "create remote project" trick. Basic functionality is there.

However, when I do a Search | PyDev search, it agonizingly processes through the files at a rate of ~2/second. This is obviously unusable. I thought that perhaps after the first pass through subsequent searches would be faster, but no joy.

Am I doing something wrong? It seems like this is a pretty basic scenario. What can I do to make this usable?

Thanks,

Matt